# Propagation delay signal time

Tags: digital-logic

Say a gate has 5 ns propagation delay. If we input a 6ns signal then does the output signal corresponding to the input last 1ns? Or do we also have to add the contamination delay to the 1ns?

Comment: why would you think that that the propagation delay applies only to one edge, either rising or falling?

Comment: idk I need to go sleep

Comment: lol ... i know exactly what you mean ... sometimes there's not enough coffee in the world

Comment: See "inertial vs transport delay". Gates are usually modelled as inertial, delay lines as transport deloy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a '6 nS signal' means a pulse of length 6 nS, and assuming that the 5 nS delay applies to both the high-going and low-going edges for the gate, then the 6 nS pulse emerges from the gate output as a 6 nS pulse, 5 nS after it went in.

In general, gates tend to have different specifications for the t<sub>PHL</sub> and t<sub>PLH</sub> times (**t**ime for **P**ropagation **H**igh to **L**ow, and *vice versa*). As a result, the pulse will be stretched or compressed by the difference between these times. This is generally known as Pulse Length Distortion. Note that for a short enough pulse, and a large enough difference between these propagation times, the pulse could disappear.